# Russell's definition of finite cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, math-history

whether the thought had been previously adumbrated, perhaps confusedly, i know not, but the name of Bertrand Russell has become associated with the assertion that:

the number $2$ is the set of all sets which contain exactly two elements.

i think there is even today some adherence to this rather neat definition.

but my elementary knowledge of these matters suffices to give rise to two questions:

a) should not Russell have said: the *proper class* of sets having exactly two elements?

b) does this imply that to understand the meaning of the symbol $2$ it is necessary to have a model of the entire class of transfinite cardinals, and to accept something like the Axiom of Choice? and is the theory of these infinities in fact research into the Kolmogorov Complexity of the concept of a finite cardinal?

Comment: Russell wasn't working within $\mathsf{ZF}$, but rather within a version of the theory of types. In this system, the collection defining $2$ may as well be called a set. And no, of course the answer to part b) is no.

Comment: What axiom(s) would you use to prove the existence of 2? Or is the existence of 2 an axiom?

Comment: In ZF, instead of defining the cardinality of $X$ as the class of all equipotent sets, we usually define it as the *set* of all equipotent sets of *minimal rank* (among all equipotent sets). This is called Scott's trick. (This is a side remark; of course Russel did nothing of the sort.)

Comment: Or you can use NF and have the Frege-Russel sets again (and a slew of other problems). As for (b) above, I can't think of why the question would even come up...

Comment: @tomasz that is interesting as i thought a first line of defence, as it were, would be to find some satisfactory way of "shrinking the domain". but even a rank beginner like myself can see that any limit ordinal and its successor give you a set with two elements, and even without the obvious transpositions there are going to be "quite a lot" of those. or should one not just  say that "2 is the cardinality of any set in bijection with $\{1,2\}$" and abandon Russell's obscurely-motivated program?

Comment: @Andreas just noticed you mentioned the theory of types. could you elaborate even slightly so i may fill out my notion of this a little? one naturally envisions the ensemble of subclasses of a proper class. surely this must have been where Russell's logic was leading him. it may be regarded as fruitless, but one wonders why the guillotine at this point?

Comment: @tamasz is there simple clarification of "rank" that a beginner might have some chance of apprehending?

Comment: @malice simply the axiom of extensionality. if i want to see whether $x=2$ is true, then i must verify that the elements of $x$ can be identified precisely with the elements of $2$

Comment: @DavidHolden: The only thing you need to know about rank to understand Scott's trick is that in ZF, every set has a well defined rank, and the class of sets of given rank is always a set. Therefore, whenever you have a (definable, but this is technical) proper class $\mathcal C$, you can find a canonical choice of a *set* of representatives of $\mathcal C$ by taking the set of elements of $\mathcal C$ of least rank.

Comment: @DavidHolden: and about your note on abandoning the Russel's definition: if you have ZFC, then you can do just that, as with axiom of choice you can show that every set is wellorderable, so we can find a unique equipotent initial ordinal, so we have a canonical choice of equipotent set. Without choice, however, there is no such canonical representative, so this kind of trick may come in handy. Also I disagree with labeling Russel's definition obscurely-motivated. It's actually the most natural definition of cardinality I can think of! The only problem is that it does not define a set.

Comment: @tomasz so without AC does the powerset of a transfinite set contain increasing chains of well-orderable subsets (though without maximal elements), or is its supply of well-orderable subsets further restricted to finite subsets, or copies of $\omega$? the latter would seem to let in the countable ordinals, though i think i read in Jech or somewhere that without AC you can have an infinite set with no countable subsets, which seems to me (in my present state of relative ignorance) marginally more counterintuitive than Banach-Tarski construxctions

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer your first question, since I'm not quite sure I understand the second one at its current form.

Russell's definition was given much before von Neumann introduced the term "proper class".

In addition to that, von Neumann suggested we choose a representative from each equivalence class, and using the axiom of choice and the definition of ordinals he suggested, we have the modern definition of cardinals instead.

> One of the first serious mathematical definitions of cardinal was the one devised by Gottlob Frege and Bertrand Russell, who defined a cardinal number |A| as the set of all sets equipollent to A. (Moore 1982, p. 153; Suppes 1972, p. 109). Unfortunately, the objects produced by this definition are not sets in the sense of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, but rather "proper classes" in the terminology of von Neumann.
>
> (Weisstein, Eric W. "Cardinal Number." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CardinalNumber.html)

Comment: thx, Asaf. yes, as i recall Russell evolved a "theory of types", though posterity has not been kind to it, so probably few now remember what he was attempting (I certainly don't). but it seems to an outsider that the notion of a "proper class" is a conceptual idempotent, a place set conveniently beyond reason, where no questions are permitted. i know everyone needs a lumber room, but it seems somehow disrespectful to house the trans-trans-finite in such an undignified location.